# Loop inside mongo query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. And in my collection, I have an array of data. And at the user end, I also have an array. I want to match the user end array with the collection array if any of the elements match with the collection array data, the should be considered as a result. Below is my collection :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f5b2f728cae440be88437f0"
    },
    "course": ["5f378f6aaf169e22d01d32d4", "5f2ba101f012a62ed011f3ae"],
    "access": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "title": "Simplification",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-09-11T08:04:02.896Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-09-11T08:04:02.896Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

And let's suppose I have an array on the user end like:-

```
var my_courses=["5f378f6aaf169e22d01d32d4","5f6449e726f13210b026635d"];
```

I want to match this array with the collections course column array. Either the array elements match with the collection or the access should be 0.

Here is my mongo query:-

```
    const videos=await Vimeo_Videos
            .find({status: 1},'$and':[ { '$and':[ { course: { '$elemMatch': {'$eq':'5f378f6aaf169e22d01d32d4' } } } ],'$or': [ { access: 0 } ] } ] }).limit(4)
```

How can I run a loop inside the query to match all array elements with a collection array? Please suggest me solution how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about the elements in the array, you could write like this-

**`{ course: {$all:['5f378f6aaf169e22d01d32d4','5f6449e726f13210b026635d']} }`**

So, your code would be-

```
const videos=await Vimeo_Videos.find({ course: {$all: '5f378f6aaf169e22d01d32d4','5f6449e726f13210b026635d']} })
```

Not sure if this what you are looking for. Hope it helps some way!

Comment: No, I'm not sure about array it is dynamic. Either there me elements or it can be an empty array. And the second thing is that it is not necessary to match the all elements of the array.